# Unable to call a dependency inside custom reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm new to Ninject. It works great on calling regular dependency classes.

However, **I'm not able to call a dependency inside a custom reflection**.

I have tried Constructor inject too. It throws exception - `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

How can I achieve it? ***I'm willing to change my design if there is a better technique.***

Thanks!

### Here is the entry point

Please not that the following code is just for a demonstration -

```
var squareCalculation = Activator.CreateInstance(
    Type.GetType("SquareCalculation")) as ICalculation;
int square = squareCalculation.Calculate(1);

var multiplyByTwoCalculation = Activator.CreateInstance(
    Type.GetType("MultiplyByTwoCalculation"))  as ICalculation;
int multiply = multiplyByTwoCalculation.Calculate(2);
```

### ICalculation

```
public interface ICalculation
{
    int Calculate(int number);
}

public class SquareCalculation : ICalculation
{
    // SquareService is not injecting.
    [Inject]
    public ISquareService SquareService { get; set; }

    public int Calculate(int number)
    {
        // *** This is the method I would like to call. It is unique. ****
        SquareService.Monday(1);

        return number * number;
    }
}

public class MultiplyByTwoCalculation : ICalculation
{
    // MultiplyByTwoService is not injecting.
    [Inject]
    public IMultiplyByTwoService MultiplyByTwoService { get; set; }

    public int Calculate(int number)
    {
        // *** This is the method I would like to call. It is unique. ****
        MultiplyByTwoService.Tuesday(1, 2, "a");

        return number * 2;
    }
}
```

### Ninject App_Start

This is just a default setting I downloaded via NuGet.

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyApp.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(MyApp.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace MyApp.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        .....

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<ISquareService>().To<SquareService>().InSingletonScope();
            kernel.Bind<IMultiplyByTwoService>().To<MultiplyByTwoService>().InSingletonScope();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code look like for the services?  I think it's more important to see the services here, rather than the calculation objects, since the services are throwing the error...  Also, that error means that the service has a constructor with parameters.  That will fail from reflection (unless you pass the parameters to reflection's ConstructorInfo object).  Ninject may have a problem with it if you haven't defined one of the constructor values in the Ninject container, most likely.

Comment: Service classes - SquareService and MultiplyByTwoService - do not have constructors; they are just a regular class with methods (which are uniques). `No parameterless constructor ..` excpetion is thrown by `SquareCalculation` and `MultiplyByTwoCalculation` if I use constructor inject. Could you please explain more about the `pass the parameters to reflection's ConstructorInfo object`? I'm new to Ninject.

Comment: If there is no constructor, I don't know why you would get that error.

Comment: Aboue example won't throw `No parameterless constructor..` exception. It only throws if I remove `[Inject]` and use constructor injection stead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Activator.CreateInstance()` you bypass Ninject, as you do when using the `new` operator. Therefore you are responsible to create them entirely or call `kernel.Inject(theNewlyCreatedObject)` yourself.

In general it is a bad idea to use `Activator.CreateInstance` directly. It's better implement a Ninject Provider, have your custom code in there and then `Bind` that type of class using `ToProvider()`